# Sequence Diagram is not generated in document from Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

A model as use case section which have sequence diagrams . I am generating documentation from use case template with some modifications to suit the organization font/style . The generated document contains the notes from UseCase: Sceanrio section and notes from General section , but its not generating the sequence diagram.

Is there a specific tag I need to include to get them generated?

Comment: Are you using EA default usecase template ? Usecase Details or Usecase Summary ?

Comment: I am using usecase Details . I also tried customizing my own from model report template , model report template outputs the sequence diagrams but not the use case . I could print the sequence title <child element> but not the diagram itself

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you've **included Diagram Section** in the defined templates and also in the Diagram properties under the Diagram tab -> Document Generation Options**** check whether Exclude image from documentation has enabled , if so please disable and re generate the document.
[image]

Arshad

Comment: That box is unchecked